Is Raydium Fee account changed 8 month ago?
For some reasons, I need to know Has Raydium's fee address changed before. The current address is '7YttLkHDoNj9wyDur5pM1ejNaAvT9X4eqaYcHQqtj2G5'. I used getSignatureForAddress but couldn't find transaction history older than 8 months ago. The last transaction signature is '2hpQeKeiNzMcfF89oWHY4DJBemSwFgu8cj5SKdUs1dKpxVqCvueAsDMweYLV8hQ7p7JCR4axWkuuQTbQDEWLy3Bp'. I need to know all the history fee address before.
